# In React, how do I deploy to multiple environments while using “homepage” property in package.json?

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, package.json

How do I set the [`homepage`](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths) property in `package.json` if it depends where I deploy to? For my testing environment, the URL would be (for example) `testing.example.com/my-app/home`. But in production, the URL would be `example.com/my-app/home`. So what do I put as the homepage property `package.json`?

Answer (score 0):

The homepage property is only information which may be useful for people who come across your package. It should only be production urls which everyone can then goto. I wouldn't expose CI or testing url's.

> The url to the project homepage.

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#homepage

For CRA, It sounds like it's trying to infer the basename, so if yours is different on different environments, you should set the basename into an environment variable, or some sort of config driven by the environment, which sets the basename for routing purposes:

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string

CRA recommends using https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd and setting `REACT_APP_API_URL` within your `.env` file

They also recommend to set homepage to `.` here https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-the-same-build-from-different-paths

Comment: Thank you for the links. This fixed my routing issue but now my app can't find the asset files. Now it's trying to look for the css and js files in `example.com./static/css/2.22a7d4ef.chunk.css`. Notice the extra dot. When I take out the dot, it goes too far back, because my files are located in `example.com/path/to/my/website/static/css/2.22a7d4ef.chunk.css`, but it's looking in `example.com/static/css/2.22a7d4ef.chunk.css`. It's skipping the path parts in the middle.